# GLM Interaction Lasso

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interaction, lasso

Apparently the stepwise produce in R is not a good way to automatically select the best glm model. Different sources suggest using lasso instead. I had a look at the glmnet packages but I do not understand how I can implement 2-way interaction terms in this packages. Also if somebody knows a webpage that explains the lasso approach in a not too mathematical way I would appreciate a lot.

Comment: *Elements of Statistical Learning* has very good coverage of regularization methods. http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/local.ftp/Springer/OLD/ESLII_print4.pdf

Comment: This Link provides the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580267/how-to-make-all-interactions-in-r-before-using-glmnet/27583931#27583931

Comment: You'd usually want to respect the marginality principle though (keeping both the main effects involved in the interactions you keep). Some form of group lasso would seem best for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the two comments are wrong, but I think the $\textit{best}$ discussion will be in Ch. 6 of 'Introduction to Statistical Learning with R' .  This book discusses both best subset and regularization techniques (ridge, lasse et al).  Finally the chapter ends with an R lab in which the 'how to' of coding in R for both methods is done.  If by 'two way ' interactions you mean simply a regression with quadratic terms in the variables, that is also explained in the book.  The book website has links to a pdf of the book, the code in the book and various other things.  It is http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/